# Debugging Apache 2.4 processes

Tags: apache-2.2, apache-2.4

Upgrading from 2.2 to 2.4 somehow mpm_itk was enabled along wiuth mpm_prefork. This problem was discussed in an\my earlier thread :
[constant mpm_itk errors in Apache error log](https://serverfault.com/questions/712830/constant-mpm-itk-errors-in-apache-error-log)
This resulted in the "mpm_itk errors" going but now I am getting these core notices instead :
[core:notice] [pid xxxxx] AH00052: child pid 4597 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
Does anyone know what I should be looking at to finally fix this?

## update

I managed to strace a process right through to its segfault, but cant really interpret it. Any help would be greatly appreciated:

```
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, [PROF], NULL, 8) = 0
getcwd("/", 4095)                       = 2
chdir("/website/public")                = 0
lstat("/website/public/index.php", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=1777, ...}) = 0
lstat("/website/public", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lstat("/website", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
setitimer(ITIMER_PROF, {it_interval={0, 0}, it_value={30, 0}}, NULL) = 0
fcntl(14, F_SETLK, {type=F_RDLCK, whence=SEEK_SET, start=1, len=1}) = 0
--- SIGSEGV {si_signo=SIGSEGV, si_code=SEGV_ACCERR,        si_addr=0x7f5a3d942028} ---
chdir("/etc/apache2")                   = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGSEGV, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_INTERRUPT, 0x7f5a3cd258d0}, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESETHAND, 0x7f5a3cd258d0}, 8) = 0
kill(24177, SIGSEGV)                    = 0
rt_sigreturn()                          = 140025556901856
--- SIGSEGV {si_signo=SIGSEGV, si_code=SI_USER, si_pid=24177, si_uid=33} ---
+++ killed by SIGSEGV +++
```

Comment: `strace` or `gdb` would be my first port of call.

Comment: Thanks womble. I'll have to read up and experiment Locally on them first as they look a bit 'scary' to dive straight into on my live ecommerce site.

Comment: Ok, I used strace to track one of the processes right through to its segfault, but I haven't really got a clue how to read it. Again, any advice would be greatly appreciated:

Comment: Sometimes you get lucky and `strace` gives you a hint; time for some `gdb` action.  Chances are you'll need to install debugging symbols for Apache to make any sense out of it.

Comment: Thanks for looking. Nothing worthwhile hey? Oh well,looks like tonights project will be gdb. Will keep updating my original post until I finally solve this...

Comment: If I were you I would be looking to submit a bug report to Apache httpd or going to the relevant apache mailing list / IRC channel (see http://httpd.apache.org/support.html) you'll likely get better support for this there.

Comment: I think the reason for the SIGSEGV is one of the following: **1.** Somehow you have installed incompatible versions of Apache and the libraries it depends upon. **2.** One of the files has been corrupted. **3.** Your hardware is faulty. **4.** You ran into a bug in the code.

Answer (score 0):

The `strace` command lists the systemcalls the application make as it is running.

If you're not de developer: Section 2 of the system manual documents system calls helping you understand what is happening.

```
fcntl(14, F_SETLK, {type=F_RDLCK, whence=SEEK_SET, start=1, len=1}) = 0
```

> `man 2 fcntl`
>
> **Name**  [**`fcntl`**](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fcntl) - manipulate file descriptor
>
> `int fcntl(int fd, int cmd, ... /* arg */ );`
>
> **Description**
>   `fcntl()` performs one of the operations described below on the open file descriptor fd. The operation is determined by cmd.
>    `fcntl()` can take an optional third argument. Whether or not this argument is required is determined by cmd. The required argument type is indicated in parentheses after each cmd name (in most cases, the required type is int, and we identify the argument using the name arg), or void is specified if the argument is not required. *...*

In other words: a read-lock is attempted on file-descriptor number 14.  To find out which file that is there should be symbolic link with the number 14, the integer representing the file in `/proc/<PID>/fd/14`.

To my eye that looks unrelated to the error in the next line but I'm no developer...:

```
--- SIGSEGV {si_signo=SIGSEGV, si_code=SEGV_ACCERR, si_addr=0x7f5a3d942028} ---
```

`si_signo=SIGSEGV`  looks like the process id your were monitoring received the segmentation fault ([`SIGSEGV`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault)) signal caused by accessing an invalid memory address, 0x7f5a3d942028,  an address which it isn't allowed to access (the SEGV_ACCERR si_code).

As to why that happened: `strace` is often unlikely to help you there.